# Calendar Control Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am displaying data from the database into vb.net calendar, but I keep on getting the error

> "SelectedDate = error BC30451: 'SelectedData' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

I am not sure what cause the error to happen. Below is my code:

```
Protected Function GetData() As Data.DataTable
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.ConnectionString = constr.ToString()
        conn.Open()
    End If

    strquery = "SELECT * FROM Event"
    _SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strquery, conn)
    datatable = New DataTable
    _SqlDataAdapter.Fill(datatable)
    Return datatable
End Function

Protected Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e Ad DayRenderEventArsgs)
    Dim dt As Data.DataTable = datatable
    Dim lblEvent = New Label()
    e.Day.IsSelectable = False
    For Each row As Data.DataRow In dt.Rows
        If Convert.ToDateTime(e.Day.Date) = Convert.ToDateTime(row("eventDate")) Then
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(New Label With {.Text = "<br/>"})
            lblEvent.Text = row("event_desc")
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(lblEvent)
            lblEvent.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: #01a9ac;border: #01a9ac;color: #fff;padding: 3px;padding-left: 50px;padding-right: 50px;")
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Protect Sub Calendar1_SelectinChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim strdatenow As String
    Dim dateTimenow = DateTime.Now()
    Dim nowDate = dateTimenow.Date
    Calendar1.SelectedDate = nowDate
    strdatenow = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString()
 End Sub
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me on this issue.

Comment: Once you name it "SelectedDat**a**" and three times you name it "SelectedDat**e**". Which one is correct?

Comment: @UweKeim I did not name it as "SelectedData" and I also couldn't find any of the "SelectedData" in my code.

Comment: Don't name your `DataTable` variable `datatable`. vb.net is case insensitive and will take this as a type. I `datatable` (please rename) is a class level variable why are you returning it from a Function?

Comment: SelectedData was in the error message.

Comment: Your code seems to have some typos. You left out Sub from the DayRender method. I suspect the root of the problem is SelectedDate - SelectedData. Do a search.

Comment: always use try catch block so you can better understand exception as well as you can get line no. from where exception thrown in stacktrace